# Android JsonElement in if condition to check equalt to

Tags: java, android, json, if-statement

I have a problrm with the `JsonElement` to chck one if condition in my project. How can i solve it ?

my string constants

```
public static final Integer RESULT_CODE_OK = 200;
public static final String RESULT_SUCCESS_OK = "true";
public static final String TAG_STATUS = "status";
public static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
```

this is my constants file.

my json elements

```
JsonElement apiStatus=response.body().get(Constants.TAG_STATUS); 
JsonElement apiSuccess=response.body().get(Constants.TAG_SUCCESS);
```

I want to check below conditoin to do some task

```
 if ((apiStatus.equals(Constants.RESULT_CODE_OK)) &&
                        (apiSuccess.equals(Constants.RESULT_SUCCESS_OK)) ) { //data received successfully
    // some task 
}else{ //while retrieving data something went wrong.
// do some task for the else.
}
```

If done like this it is always goes else loop.

I have printed the above two variable on logcat. The value is absolutly fine for the if loop. Where i am doing wrong ?

Comment: obviously it's because you are comparing `JsonElement` with as `String` ...

Comment: @Selvin  How can i compare this ?

Comment: obviously by converting `JsonElement` to a `String` ... I'm pretty sure that you would find suitable method/answer in `JsonElement's` documentation

Comment: @Selvin please see the below answer i have tried but getting the exact thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apiStatus.equals(Constants.RESULT_CODE_OK)` is false because `apiStatus` is of Type `JsonElement` where as `Constants.RESULT_CODE_OK` is `String`.
You can Use

```
if ((apiStatus.getAsInt().equals(Constants.RESULT_CODE_OK)) &&
                        (apiSuccess.getAsString.equals(Constants.RESULT_SUCCESS_OK)) ) {....}
```

Comment: How can i compare this ?

Comment: you can call .toString() on JsonElement to get String for comparison

Comment: `if ((apiStatus.toString().equals(Constants.RESULT_CODE_OK)) &&
                        (apiSuccess.toString().equals(Constants.RESULT_SUCCESS_OK)) )`

I have done like this but the condition not working

Comment: RESULT_CODE_OK is integer so you will need to call apiSuccess.getAsInt().
Updated answer with getAsString() and getAsInt() calls

Comment: Thanks , Now  it is working fine `if ((apiStatus.getAsInt()== Constants.RESULT_CODE_OK) &&
                        (apiSuccess.getAsString().equals(Constants.RESULT_SUCCESS_OK)) ) {..}`

This is the final code

Comment: can you please help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42779110/android-spinner-doesnt-showing-last-selected-item/42779519#comment72673413_42779519